# Automatically create computed fields after JSON unmarshalling

Tags: go, unmarshalling

*Simplified example*

Lets say I have a struct which I use to unmarshall some json:

```
type DataEntry struct {
    FirstName string `json:"first"`
    LastName  string `json:"last"`
    FullName  string
}
```

What I want to fill the `FullName` property, which would be `FirstName + LastName`.

---

What I am currently doing is defining a method for DataEntry, which does these kind of computations:

```
func (de *DataEntry) Compute() {
   de.FullName = de.FirstName + " " + de.LastName
}
```

and calling if after the struct gets filled from the JSON:

```
// Grab data
request, _ := http.Get("http://........")
var entry DataEntry
dec := json.NewDecoder(request.Body)
dec.Decode(&entry)

// Compute the computed fields
entry.Compute()
```

---

Is there a better way to do this?  Could I use create my own `UnmarshalJSON` and use that as a trigger to automatically compute the `FullName` field?

Comment: Why not just make `FullName` a method? This way it will always return a correct full name even if `FirstName` or `LastName` change.

Comment: Of course you can make encoding/json make use your own unmarshilng code, just implement Unmarshaller (https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler). But Ainars idea is better (at least for tiny and fast computations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case I would just turn `FullName` into a method. But if you really need to make it that way, just create a wrapper type that is also a `json.Unmarshaler`:

```
type DataEntryForJSON DataEntry

func (d *DataEntryForJSON) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, (*DataEntry)(d)); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    d.FullName = d.FirstName + " " + d.LastName
    return nil
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/g9BnytB5DG.